# Resume started activity from Service

Tags: android

As I read in several stackoverflow answeres. To start activity from the service you have to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, but it will create new instance of activity in separate task. I want to reuse already started activity. Im trying to do it from IntentService that listen for c2dm notifications.

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest for the Activity, you could set `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`.

Here's what the docs say about singleInstance:

> Only allow one instance of this activity to ever be running. This
>   activity gets a unique task with only itself running in it; if it is
>   ever launched again with the same Intent, then that task will be
>   brought forward and its Activity.onNewIntent() method called. If this
>   activity tries to start a new activity, that new activity will be
>   launched in a separate task. See the Tasks and Back Stack document for
>   more details about tasks.

And [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode) is where I got my info.

Comment: Can I do it with combination of activity flags? I don't want to change launching mode.

Comment: I believe you can, but I have not personally tested it. To find out, just add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag, then add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. I don't know for sure if it will work or not, but it will take you only about 5 or 10 minutes to set up and test.

Answer (score 1):

You must use this flag with your Intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

IF you don't want a new instance of your Activity, set launchMode for your Activity in the AndroidManifest file:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```