# calling activity from a service class

Tags: android, service

i'm developing an app where i have an activity A when it's on pause state i'm calling a service class that creates a window when the window  pressed i want to recall the activity A from the back stack again in the last pause state ,
i tried a lot of things but it keeps recreate the activity , i tried singleTask lunchMode and a lot of things but nothing works

here is my service class:

```
public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

   public static WindowManager windowManager;
   public static ImageView chatHead;
   public static View myview;

    @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
    }

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

       LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                //WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,// | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        myview = li.inflate(R.layout.dial_actionbar, null);
        chatHead=(ImageView)myview.findViewById(R.id.dialbar);
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                windowManager.removeView(myview);
                Intent goback = new Intent(ChatHeadService.this, IncomingCallScreen.class);
                goback.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                ChatHeadService.this.startActivity(goback);
                return true;

            }
        });

        windowManager.addView(myview, params);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        windowManager.removeView(myview);
    }


}
```

and here is the part where i call the service:
@Override

```
 protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(incomingCall==true)
        {
            Intent gotoBackService=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChatHeadService.class);
            startService(gotoBackService);

        }

    }
```

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750854/bring-task-to-front-on-android-intent-action-user-present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this what worked for me 
  Intent in=new Intent().setClass(ChatHeadService.this,IncomingCallScreen.class);
                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                ctx.startActivity(in);

and set launchMOde:SingleTop

Comment: plus one for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK it will recreate it every time.

Try using FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

If this not cause a conflict with your proyect needs you can set the launchmode in app manifiest.xml

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

reference:[Resume started activity from Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943240/resume-started-activity-from-service)

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i don't use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK it gives me error that he can't call the activity from outside it's context and needs this flag

Comment: Thats your problem then, doesnt it work passing this as context? as far as i know Service is a context.

Comment: the problem is i call the activity  from a background service and it requires a new task flag and this recreate my activity!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and declare this

Context ctx=this;

```
Intent in=new Intent().setClass(MyAlarmService.this,Reminder.class);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);   
ctx.startActivity(in);
```

also add android:launchMode="singleTop" in your manifest for this activty

Comment: it recreates my activity

Comment: this gives me error  "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"  because setFlags override the previous one but this worked for me   Intent in=new Intent().setClass(ChatHeadService.this,IncomingCallScreen.class);
                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                ctx.startActivity(in);

Comment: Hi marcel, you can accept my answer bcoz its the same as yours

Comment: but addFlags not setFlags for this line "in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); "because in your way you override the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and it gives error!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the new activity like this.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Activity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

The problem is you can't use startActivity method on a broadcast receiver try with this one.

```
Intent mIntent=new Intent(FinishService.this,Information.class);

sendBroadcast(mIntent);
```